# Click na Header row de uma Gridview não coloca os dados nos campos de ecran

Tags: gridview

Tenho um problema com o funcionamento numa gridview.
Quando clicko com o mouse no header row de uma linha da Gridview, os dados dos campos não passam para campos ecran definidos para o efeito.

Num outro programa, passam.

Alguém me consegue elucidar da razão desta diferença de funcionamento?

***Código não funcionando:***

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Banco_de_Imagens_Beatriz
{
    public partial class EcranDiagnostico : Form
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=POSTO0;Initial Catalog=Banco_Imagens;Integrated Security=true;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=POSTO0;Initial Catalog=Banco_Imagens;Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record
        int iddiag = 0;
        DataTable dt;
        public EcranDiagnostico()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }
        private void txt_SearchName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag where nome_diag like '" + txt_SearchName.Text + "%'", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
            ClearData();
        }
        //Insert Data
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_NomeDiag.Text != "" && txt_DescrDiag.Text != "")
            {
                txt_SearchName.Text = "";
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tb_diag(nome_diag,descr_diag) values(@nome_diag,@descr_diag)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_diag", txt_NomeDiag.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr_diag", txt_DescrDiag.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo inserido com sucesso.");
                ClearData();
                DisplayData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não introduziu dados. Introduza os dados que pretende.");
            }
        }
        //Display Data in DataGridView
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag", con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        //Clear Data
        private void ClearData()
        {
            txt_NomeDiag.Text = "";
            txt_DescrDiag.Text = "";
            iddiag = 0;
        }
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            iddiag = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            txt_NomeDiag.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_DescrDiag.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_NomeDiag.Text != "" && txt_DescrDiag.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tb_diag set nome_diag=@nome_diag,descr_diag=@descr_diag where iddiag=@iddiag", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddiag", iddiag);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome_diag", txt_NomeDiag.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descr_diag", txt_DescrDiag.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo actualizado com sucesso.");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não seleccionou nenhum registo. Seleccione o registo a actualizarr.");
            }
        }
        //Delete Record
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (iddiag != 0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tb_diag where iddiag=@iddiag", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddiag", iddiag);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Registo eliminado com sucesso.");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
            }
        }
        private void EcranDiagnostico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: esta linha de código carrega dados na tabela 'dataSet_Tabela_Diagnostico.tb_diag'. Você pode movê-la ou removê-la conforme necessário.
            //this.tb_diagTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet_Tabela_Diagnostico.tb_diag);
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tb_diag", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Código funcionando**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace InsertUpdateDeleteDemo
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record
        int ID = 0;
        DataTable dt;
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }
        private void txt_SearchName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee where FirstName like '" + txt_SearchName.Text + "%'", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
            ClearData();
        }
        //Insert Data
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_First_Name.Text != "" && txt_Last_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")
            {
                txt_SearchName.Text = "";
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_Employee(FirstName,LastName,State) values(@FirstName,@state)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_First_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_Last_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
                ClearData();
                DisplayData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
            }
        }
        //Display Data in DataGridView
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            adapt=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee",con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
        //Clear Data
        private void ClearData()
        {
            txt_First_Name.Text = "";
            txt_Last_Name.Text = "";
            txt_State.Text = "";
            ID = 0;
        }
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            txt_First_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_Last_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txt_State.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_First_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Employee set FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,State=@state where ID=@id", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_First_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_Last_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
        }
        //Delete Record
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ID!=0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tbl_Employee where ID=@id",con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
            }
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Employee", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

        private void txt_First_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_Last_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_State_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```